# Reset canvas match print composer QGIS 3

Tags: print-composer, qgis-3

Is there a way to reset the map canvas to match the layers, or layers and styling from a "locked" print composer window?
The lock layers, and lock layer styling buttons in QGIS Print Composer are great for retaining several different map layouts so you can go back and reproduce the layouts when something changes.  When I want or need to change something about the layout (e.g. add labels or add/remove a layer), however, it seems like I have to basically start from scratch to reset the map canvas to the desired set up. Is there a way to reset the layers to match the saved set up from the print composer?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to go is to create and save different style for your layers (right click on layer name in the layer panel and choose add in the style submenu)

Then you set the layers visibility and style and create different theme (click on the eyes icon on top of the layer panel)

finally on the print composer instead of "lock layers" tick the "Follow map theme" box and choose one of your theme.

This way any change you do in the style or theme set as reference is reflected in the map composer but you can still work with the other style or theme without changing anything in the composer.

Comment: This may work well in new maps going forward, but it seems like a different work flow to build map views. I was hoping there was some way to take an existing map canvas and use it to set the layer visibility on the map canvas, but it seems like this isn't possible.  Maybe it's worth trying to build a plugin...